# Android error: cannot find symbol class LocationClient

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a problem with my Android project. It can't be build because of this error: error: cannot find symbol class LocationClient. I already red that you need to use a lower version of google play services like 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'.

But when I use that one I get another error: Error:Attribute "theme" has already been defined. And when I googled that one it said that I need to use a higher version of google play services like 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'.

So I need to use both version 5.+ and 6.+ but that is not possible. Are there any solutions for this problem?

This is my gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app_id"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //tried different versions of the librarys, without success
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing that I could do is replace the LocationClient with the GoogleApiClient. Because LocationClient is deprecated. The replacement class is the GoogleApiClient. It has similar functions so its easy to replace.

Documententation: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html