# Implement google map like Uber

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am completely new to android.I am trying to implement a draggable google map like uber app.I have found out a code from somewhere,But when I try running few issues were coming like

> Error:(24, 37) error: cannot find symbol class GooglePlayServicesClient
>   Error:(26, 39) error: cannot find symbol class LocationClient

In my dependencies I have added

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

Following is the code I have used.

```
 package com.rakyow.taxifinder.taxifinder;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import   com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
// A request to connect to Location Services
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;


public static String ShopLat;
public static String ShopPlaceId;
public static String ShopLong;
// Stores the current instantiation of the location client in this object
private GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;
private TextView markerText;
private LatLng center;
private LinearLayout markerLayout;
private Geocoder geocoder;
private List<Address> addresses;
private TextView Address;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homepage);
    markerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);
    Address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adressText);
    markerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.locationMarker);
    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are
        // not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    } else { // Google Play Services are available

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
        // Create a new global location parameters object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

        /*
         * Set the update interval
         */
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(GData.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Use high accuracy
        mLocationRequest
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
        mLocationRequest
                .setFastestInterval(GData.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
        mUpdatesRequested = false;

        /*
         * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
         * callbacks.
         */
        mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient(this, this, this);
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }
}

private void stupMap() {
    try {
        LatLng latLong;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        if (mLocationClient.getLastLocation() != null) {
            latLong = new LatLng(mLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .getLatitude(), mLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .getLongitude());
            ShopLat = mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude() + "";
            ShopLong = mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude()
                    + "";


        } else {
            latLong = new LatLng(12.9667, 77.5667);
        }
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLong).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        // Clears all the existing markers
        mGoogleMap.clear();

        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                center = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;

                markerText.setText(" Set your Location ");
                mGoogleMap.clear();
                markerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                try {
                    new GetLocationAsync(center.latitude, center.longitude)
                            .execute();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });

        markerLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {

                    LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(center.latitude,
                            center.longitude);

                    Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latLng1)
                            .title(" Set your Location ")
                            .snippet("")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromResource(R.drawable.add_marker)));
                    m.setDraggable(true);

                    markerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    stupMap();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private class GetLocationAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // boolean duplicateResponse;
    double x, y;
    StringBuilder str;

    public GetLocationAsync(double latitude, double longitude) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        x = latitude;
        y = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Address.setText(" Getting location ");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
            str = new StringBuilder();
            if (geocoder.isPresent()) {
                Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();

                str.append(localityString + "");
                str.append(city + "" + region_code + "");
                str.append(zipcode + "");

            } else {
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            Address.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                    + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }
}

}
```

My requirement is something similar to this [image: Google Maps Uber].
Please help me in solving this issue.Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: i guess you need to use the latest google play lib. The error indicates that, the can'nt find LocationClient class. update your googleplay and check it if you still having the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my googleplay but still no luck..:(

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you use `GoogleApiClient` because LocationClient is no longer supported in newer versions of play-services they removed it starting Google Play Services 6.5.87 if I am not mistaken. Here is the link for the [example implementation](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/BasicLocationSample). If you really want to use LocationClient, which I do not recommend, you can use an older version of the `play-services`

Answer (score 0):

> cannot find symbol class GooglePlayServicesClient Error:(

`GooglePlayServicesClient` was removed. The documentation explicitly says that you should be using `GoogleApiClient`

> Note: If you have an existing app that connects to Google Play
>   services with a subclass of GooglePlayServicesClient, you should
>   migrate to GoogleApiClient as soon as possible.

[here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client) you can find more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) instead of Location Client.

> LocationClient is deprecated. The replacement class is the
>   GoogleApiClient. It has similar functions so its easy to replace.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141104/android-error-cannot-find-symbol-class-locationclient)